# Why should I take showers?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I can go into most bathrooms and stand under the shower-head and turn it on. Is there some purpose or benefit to taking a shower?

Comment: Knowing the creators, it's possible it actually gives a negative effect.

Comment: Is this pure coincidence that just now there is a similiar question here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36193/why-do-we-not-shower-every-night ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no reason to. It's just an interactive object for the sake of having an interactive object.

Comment: which makes the world come alive, which is good for immersion. Like the critters walking around in Guild Wars 2, without them things would look a lot more static, not good.

Comment: The concept of 'immersion' in a South Park environment is amusing to me.

Answer (score 1):

Like Professor Chaos you hate the world and it is your wish in a similar vein to Chaos's plan that leaving the showers on in every house will eventually bring doom. So yeah no point but it is neat that the state (on/off) persists when you leave.